# ruby standard for namespace import

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a few classes defined in a nested module stracture:

```
Core::UI::Components::TextView
Core::UI::Components::ImageView
Core::UI::Components::Checkbox
```

Now I have a class that wanna use this classes suppose this class is not inside the 'Core' Module.

```
class XView
  def render
    Core::UI::Components::ImageView.new('x').render
    Core::UI::Components::TextView.new('x').render
  end
end
```

I want to avoid all the module names writing so I refactor this to

```
class XView
  def render
    ui = Core::UI::Components
    ui::ImageView.new('x').render
    ui::TextView.new('x').render
  end
end
```

Is there a ruby standard for static import of module/class ? how would this be written in the ruby way?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any import construct in Ruby to do this.

If you will only need this in your `render` method, then I agree with your approach. If you may need it elsewhere, then you could define a constant in your class to alias the longer compound name, such as:

```
class Foo
...
COMPONENTS = Core::UI::Components
...
def render
  COMPONENTS::ImageView...
  ...
end
```

Alternatively, you could alias each class:

```
IMAGE_VIEW = Core::UI::Components::ImageView
...
```

I defined these constants in all upper case as a cue to the reader that these are not classes in your current module, but you could also use camel case.

Comment: Wouldn't this still need to be `COMPONENTS::ImageView` because `ImageView` is not a method.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, you're right, thanks. I've corrected it, and also edited to use the term 'alias' to clarify my intent.

Answer (score 1):

If `Core::UI::Components` is just for namespacing and does not include any method declarations then. You  can provide access to these classes via [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include) which is specifically designed for "mix-ins" e.g.

```
class XView
  include Core::UI::Components
  def render
    ImageView.new('x').render
    TextView.new('x').render
  end
end
```

Since `ImageView` and `TextView` are classes inside the module `Core::UI::Components` including this module in `XView` will allow for direct access to these classes by "including" them in the current namespace which appears to be what you are looking for. Obviously this could be done at any level e.g.

```
class XView
  include Core::UI
  def render
    Components::ImageView.new('x').render
    Components::TextView.new('x').render
  end
end
```

would also work if you needed access to other modules or classes contained in the `Core::UI` namespace.

Otherwise you could create a first class DSL for this such as

```
module Core
  module DSL
    def text_view(*args)  
      UI::Components::TextView.new(*args)
    end 
    def image_view(*args)
      UI::Components::ImageView.new(*args)
    end
  end
  extend DSL
end
```

Then the `XView` would look like

```
class XView
  def render
    Core.image_view('x').render
    Core.text_view('x').render
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach accomplishes the naming convenience, but does much more; it modifies the `include`ing class. If the poster's intention was to merely make the name more easily available (as is the case with Java imports), then this is overkill and may be undesired. Personally, my optimum point is creating a short constant alias and using that; even if it's cryptic (e.g. `CUC`), its scope is small and is easily looked up.

Comment: @KeithBennett to each their own as I feel personally your implementation is far less idiomatic. if the goal is just to shorten the namespacing then just a top level `UIComps= Core::UI::Components` would do your better yet first class DSL  inside `Core` like `def self.text_view(*args); UI::Components::TextView.new(*args); end;` then the OP could just call `Core.text_view('x')` which is not uncommon

Comment: @KeithBennett updated with a DSL implementation by the way "cryptic" is not generally the ruby way. Ruby is designed around the idea of making code readable without the need for introspection. Also `include` does not technically "modify" the class but rather injects the included module into the inheritance stack just above the including class.

Comment: Modifying the inheritance chain seems like a bad idea since the asker said he just wants to "avoid all the module names". If `Core::UI::Components` defines any methods, `include` could have surprising side-effects.

Comment: @Max that is how include works is by modifying the inheritance chain but I agree with the second part but that is implementation specific and no information was provided for such.

Comment: @Max I updated my answer to specify Module#include would be best suited if there are no method declarations in that Module. If you were the one that down voted can you explain why this is not a viable answer to "Is there a ruby standard for static import of module/class ? how would this be written in the ruby way?" since both options presented are not uncommon in ruby libraries

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, 'UIComps' is a better name than 'CUC'. That would be a solution I'd support.

Comment: @engineersmnky Idiomatic is a worthy goal, but keeping the code base free of unnecessary complexity is worthier.  Aliasing a module or class name does not change that module or class, as does 'include'. (Yes, I'm aware of how it works, but the class' behavior, i.e. the things that can be done _as if_ they were part of the original class, is still being changed.) Adding a method in the outer module to access the inner module _may_ be a good idea in some cases (e.g. when you have total control over the aliased code base),...

Comment: @engineersmnky ...but may not (e.g. if it is a third party library then you are monkey patching someone else's code over which you will have no control over time; or, if there might someday be alternate implementations (e.g. Core::AnotherKindOfUI::Components) that would make the alias confusing). I prefer the approach that modifies the aliased code the least, which is create an alias, as a local constant or in _my_ module/class hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, As someone who worked a few years on a statically typed languages, it is hard for me to accept the use of `include` because it changes my class, but it does remind a static import in java. I did ask for the ruby way to stick with the standards, wanted to make sure it didn't change for a more static language approach.